# Task causing lots of GC

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, media-player, handler

I have created a thread so that I can get the current position of my MediaPlayer without disturbing the UI but I seen to be getting a lot of garbage collection when the timer is running, is it normal?

Also to avoid the risk of spamming, does anyone else know a better way to display the position of a MediaPlayer which is more efficient?

```
private void processThread() {

        final MediaPlayer MP;
        MP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sleepaway);
        MP.start();

        new Thread(){

            public void run(){              


                handler.post(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                        myText.setText(getTimeString(MP.getCurrentPosition()));    
                        handler.postDelayed(this,10);

                    }  

                });


            }

        }.start();

    }
```

The messages I receive about three times a second:

```
08-14 05:44:27.385: DEBUG/dalvikvm(32100): GC freed 10820 objects / 524656 bytes in 75ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread you are creating is completely useless, just do the post(Runnable). Also, you are creating an infinite "loop" with your postDelayed().

Comment: do you think that it will slow down my UI though?

Comment: It can't be worse than your current code. Like I said, your thread is useless and you are going to create MANY thread with this code. Which is going to be expensive.

Comment: @RomainGuy - handler.postDelayed() creates new threads or schedules a runnable to be executed in the current thread?